# In Risen, how do I brew beer?

Tags: risen

I had one of the NPCs, Rhobart, teach me the Alchemy skill and explain me the recipe. But then, when I try to activate the Alchemy table, my character won't do anything.

Comment: Can somebody with enough Reputation change the used tag "rpg" to "risen" please?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is no possibility to brew Beer in Risen!

When you first get the alchemy skill, you will get the recipe for the small heal potion.
Right-Click on the Recipe in your inventory, then you will be able to create those potions at the alchemy table.